# Taskbar location

Tags: c#

How can i detect where the taskbar is located? I need to know for displaying my notification in the right corner. Thanks

Edit:
Thank you Hans Passant. I used that with this to get location. I hope is ok.

```
GetTaskbarLocation(TaskbarPosition.GetTaskbarPosition());

private void GetTaskbarLocation(Rectangle rc)
{
    if (rc.X == rc.Y)
    {
        if (rc.Right < rc.Bottom)
            taskbarLocation = TaskbarLocation.Left;
        if (rc.Right > rc.Bottom)
            taskbarLocation = TaskbarLocation.Top;
    }
    if (rc.X > rc.Y)
        taskbarLocation = TaskbarLocation.Right;
    if (rc.X < rc.Y)
        taskbarLocation = TaskbarLocation.Bottom;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    public static Rectangle GetTaskbarPosition() {
        var data = new APPBARDATA();
        data.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(data);
        IntPtr retval = SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ref data);
        if (retval == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception("Please re-install Windows");
        return new Rectangle(data.rc.left, data.rc.top,
            data.rc.right - data.rc.left, data.rc.bottom - data.rc.top);

    }

    // P/Invoke goo:
    private const int ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SHAppBarMessage(int msg, ref APPBARDATA data);
    private struct APPBARDATA {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public int uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }
    private struct RECT {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure this code is complete. [MSDN has the following in the documentation for `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): *You must specify the cbSize **and hWnd** when sending this message;* [This](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shappbarmessage) and [this](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26977) both look for a window called `Shell_TrayWnd` to use as the `hWnd`.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought it was redundant but on Win8 you can have more than one task bar. [And this guy seems to be having some problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20298740/issue-with-shappbarmessage-for-taskbar-position-on-windows-server-2008r2/20298931#20298931) with very similar code. Which is how I came across this answer.

Comment: Has taskbar looks strange, 2008R2 should have the round Start button orb.  The exception message might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

```
SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS)
```

See the [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108%28VS.85%29.aspx) Function and the [ABM_GETTASKBARPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787949%28VS.85%29.aspx) Message for more info and the pinvoke page for [SHAppBarMessage](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.shappbarmessage) has a VB.Net sample that shouldn't be too difficult to translate.

Answer (score 1):

The [SHAppBarMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762108(VS.85).aspx) function will return you information about the taskbar if you pass in the [ABM_GETTASKBARPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773184(v=VS.85).aspx) message. It has an out parameter which is a pointer to [APPBARDATA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773184(v=VS.85).aspx) that contains the screen cooridinates of the task bar. You can use to work out where on screen it is.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably best to use the available API: [`NotifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160065.aspx):

```
void Form1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    notifyIcon1.Visible = true;
    notifyIcon1.ShowBalloonTip(20000, "Information", "This is the text",
        ToolTipIcon.Info );
}
```

Comment: for notification I'm using a form :) i should mention that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Java, using JNA (adapted from other C# solutions above)

```
public static Rectangle getTaskbarPosition() throws Exception {
    APPBARDATA data = new APPBARDATA();
    data.cbSize = new WinDef.DWORD(data.size());
    WinDef.UINT_PTR retval = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, data);
    if (retval == null) {
        throw new Exception("Please re-install Windows");
    }

    return new Rectangle(data.rc.left, data.rc.top, data.rc.right - data.rc.left, data.rc.bottom - data.rc.top);
}
```