# How to position a form over taskbar, not above it?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am trying to create an application that will start up over the Windows' taskbar on the bottom left corner. I want the form to overlap the taskbar. All my methods ends on making the form load above the taskbar.

Comment: Be aware that the taskbar may not be at the bottom of the screen. People can move it.

Comment: true, that also is a problem. If the solution can't be dynamic to the taskbar position, then think about the taskbar being on bottom, since that's what most people have and it's the default position.

Comment: I think you'll find a good conversation about this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7458611/how-to-determine-which-screen-the-taskbar-is-on  and here: http://winsharp93.wordpress.com/2009/06/29/find-out-size-and-position-of-the-taskbar/

Comment: Are you trying to hide or prevent the user from clicking the Start button?  Be advised, that besides the fact that the task bar might not be at the bottom of the screen, some people may have changed the size of their taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the form's property [TopMost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx) to `true` to achieve that

Comment: I'm not looking for a way to have it stay on top of the taskbar. I'm looking for a way to have the form start on top of the taskbar (preferably the bottom left corner).

Comment: @user1877499 ok, it's started on top of the taskbar, what should happen next?