# Issue with SHAppBarMessage for TaskBar Position on Windows Server 2008R2

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, windows-server-2008-r2, taskbar, shell32

I am having a really strange issue with `SHAppBarMessage`, have been trying out different things for few hours now but i am not getting it. I am trying to get the TaskBar Position. It works fine on Windows 8 but on Windows Server the return value is `SHAppBarMessage`.

The following code from [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3677319/1823643) works from fine on Windows 8, but on Windows 2008R2 it has a strange behavior.

```
    public static System.Drawing.Rectangle GetTaskbarPosition()
    {
        var data = new APPBARDATA();
        data.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(data);
        IntPtr retval = SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ref data);
        if (retval == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Exception("Please re-install Windows");
        return new System.Drawing.Rectangle(data.rc.left, data.rc.top,
            data.rc.right - data.rc.left, data.rc.bottom - data.rc.top);
    }

    // P/Invoke goo:
    private const int ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5;
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SHAppBarMessage(int msg, ref APPBARDATA data);
    private struct APPBARDATA
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public int uEdge;
        public RECT rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }
```

I am totally out of ideas. As it should work as it is. But i dont know why it is not working. Am i missing something?

[image: Seeing is believing]

Comment: Have you tried re-installing Windows?

Comment: No not yet was trying to figure it out first.

Comment: I don't know whether it's the default, but pinvoke.net includes a `StructLayoutAttribute` on `APPBARDATA` and `RECT` http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/APPBARDATA.html

Comment: i did try that as well, Infact initially my call was with StructLayout. As i said, have been looking into it so i have already tried all the possible things that comes to my mind or found it over internet.

Comment: What happens if you run it on AnyCPU/x86/x64 architectures explicitly?

Comment: On all the Architectures it behaves the same way, infact i tried it on .Net4 and .Net4.5 as well, But no gain.

Comment: Well I have no ideas left other than really wild guesses. It appears you're using a console app? Put `STAThreadAttribute` on the `Main` function. And try the code again, but in a WinForms project. Hook the code up to a button?

Comment: Embarcadero (the Delphi guys) have an example that explicitly gets the `HWND` for `Shell_TrayWnd` first. http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26977

Comment: I better try it on some other machine then.

Comment: You are violating this site's license.  You must include a link to the post where you obtained the code as well as a link to the author of the post.

Comment: I have added the link thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation for `ABM_GETTASKBARPOS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787949(v=vs.85).aspx):

> ```
> fResult = (BOOL) SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, pabd);
> ```
>
> `pabd`
>
> A pointer to an `APPBARDATA` structure whose rc member receives the bounding rectangle, in screen coordinates, of the taskbar. **You must specify** the `cbSize` and **`hWnd`** when sending this message; all other members are ignored.

Emphasis mine.

[This](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/26977) Delphi code sample suggests as much, it looks for a window by the name of `Shell_TrayWnd`:

```
// 'Shell_TrayWnd' is the name of the task bar's window
AppData.Hwnd := FindWindow('Shell_TrayWnd', nil);
```

Comment: Yes you are hWnd should be provided, but no gain. My believe is now getting stronger that this is OS installation issue. Something's corrupted may be. But thanks for your held.