# Open WPF window near to notification area with support multiply monitors

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, tray

My wpf application should open a window nearing to notification area. When the user clicks on the tray icon opens a window. So i need the window on the same screen where the notification area. For now i just getting taskbar location: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8581546/1502011
and taskbar rectlange on the screen https://stackoverflow.com/a/3677319/1502011 and then i use it for locate my window like:

```
//xaml.cs
var taskBarLocation = GetTaskBarLocation();
var taskBarPosition = GetTaskbarPosition();

this.Left = taskBarLocation == Location.Left
            ? taskBarPosition.Width
            : SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - Width;

this.Top = taskBarLocation == Location.Top
            ? taskBarPosition.Height
            : SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - Height;
```

It works only if the notification area are placed at the primary screen. As i understood i should use WinApi for place my window on other monitor but i even don't know how to find screen with the notification area. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried browsing through the `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens` property? it's an array of type `Screen`. You can check if the screen is the primary screen. And isn't the notification area connected to the taskbar?

Comment: Thanks for your responds! I didn't know the wpf window coords points to display coords and i can simply move the window by set it coordinates out of primary screen. I also didn't know that SHAppBarMessage returns display coords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, since

1) Wpf window location don't care about monitors ( it's work on "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Display\Screen Resolution" coordinates, not on current screen coordinates )

2) WinApi method SHAppBarMessage(5, ref data) also works in global coordinates

3) Each screen object have [Bounds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.forms.screen.bounds(v=vs.110).aspx) property that represents place of the screen at global coordinates

The solution is quite simple:

```
public static class TaskBarLocationProvider
{
    // P/Invoke goo:
    private const int ABM_GETTASKBARPOS = 5;

    [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SHAppBarMessage(int msg, ref AppBarData data);

    /// <summary>
    /// Where is task bar located (at top of the screen, at bottom (default), or at the one of sides)
    /// </summary>
    private enum Dock
    {
        Left = 0,
        Top = 1,
        Right = 2,
        Bottom = 3
    }

    private struct Rect
    {
        public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
    }

    private struct AppBarData
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public IntPtr hWnd;
        public int uCallbackMessage;
        public Dock Dock;
        public Rect rc;
        public IntPtr lParam;
    }

    private static Rectangle GetTaskBarCoordinates(Rect rc)
    {
        return new Rectangle(rc.Left, rc.Top,
            rc.Right - rc.Left, rc.Bottom - rc.Top);
    }

    private static AppBarData GetTaskBarLocation()
    {
        var data = new AppBarData();
        data.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(data);

        IntPtr retval = SHAppBarMessage(ABM_GETTASKBARPOS, ref data);

        if (retval == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception("WinAPi Error: does'nt work api method SHAppBarMessage");

        }

        return data;
    }

    private static Screen FindScreenWithTaskBar(Rectangle taskBarCoordinates)
    {
        foreach (var screen in Screen.AllScreens)
        {
            if (screen.Bounds.Contains(taskBarCoordinates))
            {
                return screen;
            }
        }

        return Screen.PrimaryScreen;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate wpf window position for place it near to taskbar area
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="windowWidth">target window height</param>
    /// <param name="windowHeight">target window width</param>
    /// <param name="left">Result left coordinate <see cref="System.Windows.Window.Left"/></param>
    /// <param name="top">Result top coordinate <see cref="System.Windows.Window.Top"/></param>
    public static void CalculateWindowPositionByTaskbar(double windowWidth, double windowHeight, out double left, out double top)
    {
        var taskBarLocation = GetTaskBarLocation();
        var taskBarRectangle = GetTaskBarCoordinates(taskBarLocation.rc);
        var screen = FindScreenWithTaskBar(taskBarRectangle);

        left = taskBarLocation.Dock == Dock.Left
            ? screen.Bounds.X + taskBarRectangle.Width
            : screen.Bounds.X + screen.WorkingArea.Width - windowWidth;

        top = taskBarLocation.Dock == Dock.Top
            ? screen.Bounds.Y + taskBarRectangle.Height
            : screen.Bounds.Y + screen.WorkingArea.Height - windowHeight;
    }
```

and usage in xaml.cs

```
    private void SetWindowPosition()
    {
        double left, right;
        TaskBarLocationProvider.CalculateWindowPositionByTaskbar(this.Width, this.Height, out left, out right);

        Left = left;
        Top = right;
    }
```